# windows command config file?

Tags: windows, configuration-files, windows-scripting

I'm running a few different windows command scripts that all reference the same directory. The directory I want to reference changes from day to day depending on what I'm working on. I've looked into taking command line args, but I think the more elegant solution would be to have all the scripts reference some sort of config file, if such a thing is possible. Then I could change the directory address one place to change all of my standard command scripts. If it's not abundantly clear, I'm new to windows scripting.

**Q:** Is there a way to retrieve data from an external config in a windows command script?

PS - Don't be limited by my question, if you think you have a better solution for what I'm trying to do, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to use an environment variable.

eg:

```
set my_path=c:\foo\bar
```

then in the script you can use `%my_path%` and it will be expanded for you.